# Time-based allocation of assets

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I am working on a resource allocation problem and was looking for a algorithm that I could use. Here's are the data items

1. Each timeslot is 15 mins in duration
2. There are n number of a resource type

A resource can be requested for n timeslots (e.g. 1 hour = 4 timeslots) at a certain time (e.g. 10 am)

Input to Algorithm: Request n resources for n timeslots at h hour, would a resource be available to fulfil the request.

e.g. can I hire a car for 1 hour at 10:00 am, from a inventory of 4 cars, however 2 of these cars are already booked between 9:30 and 10:00 am.

Any pointers on how this can done, I'll be very grateful

Al

Comment: Is all the slot same size I mean 15 minutes? 
Please share what should be the input and output of your problem.

Comment: Yes @Merom , all timeslots are 15 minutes, if you need an hour, select 4 timeslots (consecutive) Inputs : 1. An array of bookings in the system, e.g. [9:00 am, 4 timeslots], [9:00 am 2 timeslots] 2. Request : [9:00am , 2 slots] i.e. Can a request for 2 timeslots from 09:00 am to 09:30 am be fulfilled